# Quick probability question on rolling 2 Die

Tags: probability, dice

If I flip a coin and it lands on heads I roll a fair dice n times. If the coin lands on tails I roll a biased dice n times. Let $X_i$ denote the score of the $i$th roll of the fair die and $Y_i$ the score of the $i$th roll of the biased die.

Would this be how you would denote the sum of the scores on the die?

$$S_n=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n{Y_i}$$

Comment: Not sure what this represents.  The sum of the scores is either $\sum X_i$ or $\sum Y_i$, probaiblity $\frac 12$ for either.  Are you trying to compute an expectation?

Comment: yes I'm asked to compute $E(S_n)$

Comment: would it be $E(S_n) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n{E(X_i)} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n{E(Y_i)}$

Comment: Ok, well then it is true that $E[S_n]=\frac 12\times \sum E[X_i]+\frac 12\times \sum E[Y_i]$.  Of course all the $E[X_i]= 3.5$ but we don't know any $E[Y_i]$ from the given information.

Comment: Crossed comments.  Yes, that formula is correct.

Comment: For future reference, consider giving respondents a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the description of your procedure/game, I take

> the sum of the scores on the die

to mean that after you decide which die you roll, you roll it $n$ times and add up each value rolled.

So, the score should be denoted by 
$$S$$
without the subscript. Your score is given by
$$S = I\sum_{k = 1}^n X_k+(1-I)\sum_{k = 1}^n Y_k$$
where 
$$I = \begin{cases} 1,& \text{flipped heads}\\
0,& \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

---

Addendum:

I guess you could keep the $n$, it didn't really occur to me.

Regardless, there should be an indicator there:
$$S_n = I\sum_{k = 1}^n X_k+(1-I)\sum_{k = 1}^n Y_k.$$

If we were given the distribution of the $Y_i$, then
$$E[Y_i] = \sum_{k = 1}^6 k P(Y_i = k) = \gamma.$$
Assuming independence across rolls, we have
\begin{align*}
E[S_n] &= E\left[I\sum_{k=1}^nX_k+(1-I)\sum_{k = 1}^nY_i\right] \\
&= E[I]\sum_{k = 1}^nE[X_k]+E[1-I]\sum_{k = 1}^nE[Y_k] \tag1\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot n\cdot \frac 72+ \frac{1}{2}\cdot n\cdot \gamma\tag2\\
&=\frac{n}{2}\cdot\frac{7+2\gamma}{2}
\end{align*}
where in

1. The indicator is independent of $X_i$ and $Y_i$, and
2. We know $E[X_i] = 3.5$ since it is fair and follows a discrete uniform distribution on $\{1,2,\dotsc, 6\}$.